# Is this description of etiology of celiac disease correct?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, proteins, autoimmune, celiac-disease

There is a detailed and, to my inexpert eyes, plausible description of the etiology of celiac disease and other autoimmune disorders posted here: http://no-gluten.org/CeliacDisease.htm

Is it is at all accurate? If any of it is speculative or incorrect, which parts are those? Red flags to me are that it cites no sources and is much more detailed than any other description of celiac that I've seen. But, again, it does coincide with what little I do know of human immune biology.